# Passing "local" variables in Python by changing and importing modules?

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces, scope

I had to read and fix some really bad scripts today, and I'm baffled because I don't understand why they worked at all. To be clear, I would never do something like this. My question refers to **how namespaces work in this case**, not why it is a bad idea or how to do this better.

Anyway, the situation in its simplest form can be reproduced with two files.

`test.py`:

```
import math
math.myvar = "Is this a local variable?"
math.pi = 1.2345
import u
```

`u.py`:

```
import math
print(math.myvar)
print(math.pi)
```

Now, to my surprise running `python test.py` will print `myvar` and the wrong value for pi. Of course, without the `import math` in `u.py` it will not print `myvar`. How does this happen? I though imported modules were entirely local in scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules are global singletons. They are stored in the `sys.modules` mapping, to prevent having to load every module each time it is used somewhere.

All globals in a module are exposed as attributes on the module object; `math.pi` is one such global. You can alter these globals by assigning to them, and because modules are singleton objects, *every* reference to the module object will see the change.

Remember, Python names are *references*; the name `math` is indeed 'local' to your module, but it is still a reference to the global `<module 'math' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'>` object.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. A little bit of research shows that the docs actually mention this when describing import internals: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module

Comment: So I suppose I could purge the previous change by doing `sys.modules.pop('math')` and importing again.

Comment: @Karol: or using the [`reload()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload), although that'll *retain* the `math.myvar` name. This is an explicit feature of `reload()`.